# How to get the value in a nested list using itertools.zip_longest

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, python-itertools

i have two lists and i want to use itertool.zip_longest to compare some values in the list and do something else, this is the code I've written so far

```
import itertools

List1  = [['a'],['B']]
List2 = ['A','b','C']

for a in List1:
    for i in itertools.zip_longest(a,List2):
        print (i)
```

but this is the result I'm getting, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this behavior

```
('a', 'A')
(None, 'b')
(None, 'C')
('B', 'A')
(None, 'b')
(None, 'C')
```

I'm trying to get something like this

```
('a', 'A')
('B', 'b')
(None, 'C')
```

so i can compare the values directly

Comment: It is not clear why you expect the second output. If you want that, `List1` should surely look like `['a', 'B']` - maybe flatten it first?

Comment: sorry i'm still a newbie in python, i think i was trying to flatten(i.e get the values in the list) first with the first for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to flatten list1:

```
List1  = [['a'],['B']]
List2 = ['A','b','C']

print(list(itertools.zip_longest((b for a in List1 for b in a),List2))
[('a', 'A'), ('B', 'b'), (None, 'C')]
```

If you want to compare just iterate over the zip_longest object unpacking:

```
for a, b in itertools.zip_longest((b for a in List1 for b in a),List2):
    if a == b:
        # do whatever
```

To set a particular defualt value use fillvalue:

```
List1  = [['a'],['B']]
List2 = ['A','b','C']

print(list(itertools.zip_longest((b for a in List1 for b in a),List2,fillvalue="foo")))
[('a', 'A'), ('B', 'b'), ('foo', 'C')]
```

Comment: how can i remove the None in the third tuple or better still set a default value for it

Comment: @danidee, specify `fillvalue=whatever` in zip_longest

Answer (score 1):

For that result you need to flatten the list `a` that you can do it with `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(itertools.chain(*List1),List2))
[('a', 'A'), ('B', 'b'), (None, 'C')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but i think i'll need to flatten list1 to get ['a','B'] so i can compare like this:    if List1[0] in List2: do_something() or is there any way i can compare the values

Comment: `itertools.chain(*List1)` flattens the list for you.

Comment: @danidee welcome! As achampio says `itertools.chain(*List1)` flattens the list!

Comment: how can i remove the None in the third tuple or better still set a default value for it