# How to print long list with a short nested list using itertools.zip_longest?

Tags: python

I have following data:

```
HEADERS = ['OTHER','DIFF']
my_hosts = [['hostc', '10.0.0.4' ], ['hosta', '10.0.0.2'], ['hostb', '10.0.0.3'] ]
other_hosts = ['hosta', 'hostb', 'hostc', 'hostd' ]
```

The problem here is that one list is "longer" than the other in terms of number of elements. I have tried to experiment with the `itertools.zip_longes`, however I'm not able to print the elements in the nested list separately. Reason is: When it is suppose to print `hostd` it will say `index out of range`.

What I have tried

```
print(("{} \t {}").format(HEADERS[0], HEADERS[1]))

for my, other in itertools.zip_longest(sorted(my_hosts), sorted(other_hosts), fillvalue=''):
    print(("{} \t {}: {}).format(other, my[0][0], my[0][1]))
```

**Desired output:**

```
OTHER       DIFF
hosta       hosta: 10.0.0.2
hostb       hostb: 10.0.0.3
hostc       hostc: 10.0.0.4
hostd
```

Also had a quick look at: [How to get the value in a nested list using itertools zip-longest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502527/how-to-get-the-value-in-a-nested-list-using-itertools-zip-longest)

Comment: The first element in the first list doesn't match the structure of the rest. Pull them out into separate variables instead.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. Updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

```
import itertools

HEADERS = ['OTHER','DIFF']
my_hosts = [['hostc', '10.0.0.4' ], ['hosta', '10.0.0.2'], ['hostb', '10.0.0.3'] ]
other_hosts = ['hosta', 'hostb', 'hostc', 'hostd' ]

print(("{} \t {}").format(HEADERS[0], HEADERS[1]))

for a,b in itertools.zip_longest(sorted(other_hosts),sorted(my_hosts)):
  if b is not None:
    print(("{} \t {}: {}").format(a, b[0], b[1]))
  else:
    print(a)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
OTHER    DIFF
hosta    hosta: 10.0.0.2
hostb    hostb: 10.0.0.3
hostc    hostc: 10.0.0.4
hostd
```